# Is Javascript in node.js different from browser (Chrome)?

Tags: pug

In the **same** .jade file I have:

```
script.
  if (user)
    ...//using jQuery to change color theme
```

and also:

```
li
-if (user)
  a(href='/lougout')
-else
  a(href='/login')
```

If `user` is not present, the first results in the following error in the Chrome:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: user is not defined

The second works without problems at all, ie the node.js server/Jade engine does not complain.

Why is it happening this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.` after `script` means its contents are literal. `if (user)` is emitted into the `<script>`, not evaluated:

```
<script>
if (user)
  ... // using jQuery to change color theme
</script>
```

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clearer that the first is executing in the browser and the second is in the server.

Comment: @OldGeezer: So `user` isn’t defined in the browser…

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. My question was using an incorrect illustration. What I wanted to ask was `if (someobject) ...` does not cause an error in Jade or node.js even when `someobject` is not declared.

Comment: @OldGeezer: Ah, okay. Jade rewrites uses of undeclared variables to point to the data you pass to your template (to the effect of `if (user)` → `if (data.user)`), so they’ll never throw.